# Hint acts weird

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, hint

I have an edittext that acts weird when I set a hint to it.

XML :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
    android:background="@android:drawable/edit_text"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingRight="0dip" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pinDisplay"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.85"
        android:background="@null"
       />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/backspace"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_delete" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Code :

```
private float hintTextSize = 24;

private void initializeInputText() {
    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pinDisplay);
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    input.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
    input.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, hintTextSize);
    input.setHint("Kies pincode");
    input.setCursorVisible(false);

    input.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            return true;
        }
    });

    input.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLengthInput) });
    input.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            input.setError(null);

            if (s.length() >= maxLengthInput) {
                input.setCursorVisible(false);
                btnOk.setEnabled(true);
                btnOk.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00B32D")); //Green
            } else {
                btnOk.setEnabled(false);
                btnOk.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#B8B8B8")); //Light gray
                input.setCursorVisible(true);
                input.setSelection(input.getText().length());
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (!input.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                input.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, textSize);
            } else {
                input.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, hintTextSize);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This is the first:

[image]

But when I add a number the edittext grows and takes a lot more space.

[image]

What can be the cause ?

Comment: Did you try setting the padding of your `EditText` in your xml? This is what changes on the second screen.

Comment: I've just set it to 0dp, but this doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the following code in your class:

```
         input.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, hintTextSize);
```

and try